# getting empty response from PHP server

Tags: php, android, json, http-post

Hi friends I am trying to add PHP web services to my ANDROID application, my android code:

```
userName = userNameField.getText().toString();
passWord = passWordField.getText().toString();

try {
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("username", userName);
json.put("password", passWord);
json.put("device_type", "Android");
json.put("lat", "0.0");
json.put("long", "0.0");

JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject();
json1.put("method_name", "checkLogin");
json1.putOpt("body", json);

HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
        TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);
request.setEntity(new StringEntity(json1.toString()));
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String response = client.execute(request, responseHandler);

Toast.makeText(this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Throwable t) {
Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed: " + t.toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Request:

```
 {"method_name":"checkLogin","body":   {"username":"someone@some.com","password":"password","device_type":"android","lat":"","long":""}}
```

expected Response:

```
[{"status":"1","message":"Login successfully","data":{"id":"xx","username":"someone@some.com","first_name":"xxx","last_name":"yyy","gender":"xxx","relationship":"xxxx","birthdate":"xxxx","hometown":"","major":null,"class":null,"house":null,"device_type":"iphone","current_location_lat":"0.0","current_location_lon":"0.0","profile_image":"no_male_user.png","is_login":"1","created":"2012","status":"1","tag":[{"id":"x","tag_name":"xxxx"},{"id":"x","tag_name":"xxx xxx"}]}}]
```

main.php

```
<?php
require_once('configure.php');
require_once('db.php');
require_once("request.php");
require_once("error_msg.php");
require_once("./includes/JSON.php");

$json = $_POST['json'];

$objRequest = new Request($json);
$rows = $objRequest -> main();
echo $rows;
?>
```

request.php

```
<?php
require_once("./includes/JSON.php");
require_once("db.php");
require_once('SimpleImage.php');
class Request
{
function __construct($json)
{
    $this -> array1 = @json_decode(stripcslashes(trim($json)));
}
function main()
{
    $objDb = new DB();
    $conn = $objDb -> getConnection();

    if(!$conn)
        return Error :: $DB_CONN_ERROR." ".$DB_CONN_ERROR_DESC;
    else
    {
        if($this -> array1 -> method_name == 'checkLogin')
            return $this -> getLoginFlag($this -> array1 -> body);
    }
}
// For Login Start
function getLoginFlag($body)
{
    $username = trim($body -> username);
    $password = ($body -> password);
    $device_type = trim($body -> device_type);

    $this -> rs_login = DB :: selectLoginRecord($body);
    $arr_resp = array();
    $retArray = array();
    $tagListArray = array();
    if(mysql_num_rows($this -> rs_login) > 0)
    {
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($this -> rs_login))
        {
                $arr_resp = array("id"=> $rows['id'],"username"=> $rows['username'],"first_name"=> ucfirst($rows['first_name']),"last_name"=>ucfirst($rows['last_name']),"gender"=>$rows['gender'],"relationship"=>$rows['relationship'],"birthdate"=>date('M d, Y', strtotime($rows['birthdate'])),"hometown"=>$rows['hometown'],"major"=>$rows['major'],"class"=>$rows['class'],"house"=>$rows['house'],"device_type"=>$rows['device_type'],"current_location_lat"=>$rows['current_location_lat'],"current_location_lon"=>$rows['current_location_lon'],"profile_image"=>$rows['profile_image'],"is_login"=>$rows['is_login'],"created"=>date('Y', strtotime($rows['created'])),"status"=>$rows['status']);   
        }
        $this -> rs_tag_list = DB :: selectTagList($arr_resp['id']);
        if(mysql_num_rows($this -> rs_tag_list) > 0)
        {   
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($this -> rs_tag_list))
            {
                $tagListArray['tag'][]= array("id"=> $rows['id'],"tag_name"=> $rows['tag_name']);   
            }
        }

        $finalArray = array_merge($arr_resp,$tagListArray);
        $retArray[] = array("status"  => "1","message" => "Login successfully","data" => $finalArray);
    }
    else
    {
        $retArray[] = array("status" => "0","message" => "The username or password you entered is incorrect");  
    }

    return json_encode($retArray);
}
// End Login

}

?>
```

but am getting empty response, can anybody please help me.
Here I am using JSON for data parsing.
thanks for your response friends.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have created a constant String for URL

Comment: possible duplicate of [sending HTTP request to PHP web server by using JSON, in ANDROID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275467/sending-http-request-to-php-web-server-by-using-json-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the php code if it gets the required value correctly and executing the the desired method exactly ?

Comment: Ok let do one by one. First print those requested variables in php page in the server. Then check print those inside the login method. Else just comment everything and print "test"; Just debug step by step. See whether you get any response. Else you have problem with your java code. See if you have desired permission in manifest ?

Comment: HI Tuhin, thanks for your response. I have added the PHP code to this question, this code is working fine in iPhone. Can you please help me

Comment: Just do one thing. write `echo "hi"; die; before the line $json = $_POST['json']; and look if you get any response.